# Html dentro de "echo" php

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para por isso:

`<td><a href="edita.php?id=<?php echo $objProg->getid();?>">Alterar</a></td>`

Dentro de um `echo` no php ?

Comment: <?php echo '<td><a href="edita.php?id=' . $objProg->getid() . '">Alterar</a></td>'; ?>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode [concatenar](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php) *(ou seja juntar duas ou mais strings)* dentro do seu "echo" para ter esse resultado *(como já foi postado como comentário)*.

```
<?php
echo '<td><a href="edita.php?id=' . $objProg->getid() . '">Alterar</a></td>';
?>
```

Outro método que "recomendo" você a conhecer e testar seria o [HereDoc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) que irá lhe permitir adicionar as variáveis sem se preocupar com as aspas e etc., tendo o mesmo efeito.

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT
<td><a href="edita.php?id=$objProg->getid()">Alterar</a></td>
EOT;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar da forma que o SK15 falou, ou pode ao invés de usar o echo escrever direto no HTML e apenas inserir a info em php por exemplo:

```
<td>
   <a href="edita.php?id=<?=$objProg->getid();?>">
       Alterar
   </a>
</td>
```

Utiliza o `<?=` para poupar código e agilizar o processamento com um código amis limpo! E facilita... E se esse pedaço de código for usado dentro de um if, ou else, ou while, ou for... Feche o php antes dele e abra novamente após!

Comment: Vale lembrar que essa forma é afetada pela diretiva [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) ou seja em PHP versão menor que 5.4.0 ele não irá funcionar se não estiver ativa apenas no PHP 5.4.0 em diante ela não é afetada.