# Como dar echo em $arrayReturn e código html

Tags: php

Como eu faço para dar um echo neste código todo?

```
<li>Número: 
    <strong><?=$arrayReturn['numero'];?></strong>
</li>
```

Comment: @Everson, eu preciso dar um echo (em tudo) acima. o primeiro código que você mandou não funciona. e quanto a pergunta duplicada também não se encaixa. (inclusive o EOT)

Comment: você quer mostrar na tela o código html sem executá-lo, correto?

Comment: @J.Doe leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120559/57801 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59934/57801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retire os delimitadores `<? ?>`, inclua o código em aspas duplas e faça a concatenação:

```
<?php
echo "<li>Número: 
    <strong>".$arrayReturn['numero']."</strong>
</li>";
?>
```

Comment: Também já havia tentando
Syntax error, unexpected $EOF, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Deu! Eu já tinha tentando assim, mas usei aspas simples e então nem parei para pensar! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para dar `echo` em um array você pode usar a função `print_r()`

```
<strong> <?php print_r($arrayReturn);?> </strong>
```

Caro queira deixar o código pré formatado na tela você pode fazer

```
<pre>
    <strong> <?php print_r($arrayReturn);?> </strong>
</pre>
```

Comment: Aí fica o erro de syntax já que o < do <li não é esperado.

Comment: Tem como ser mais detalhado no que você quer? Sua pergunta está muito vaga e não tem uma clareza da sua dúvida. Qual a estrutura desse array? qual o resultado esperado do código?

Comment: Eu apenas quero dar um echo no código acima
<?php echo "<li>Número: 
    <strong><?=$arrayReturn['numero'];?></strong>
</li>";>

Sei que assim não funciona. Como seria o correto?

Comment: Se for só isso não tem nada de errado com seu código, exceto pela tag de impressão reduzida do PHP que não é a mais aconselhável. Para saber onde está o erro você deve colocar a estrutura do array que você esta usando.